# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: веб-сервер, администрирование

хочу обновить язык php на сервере сайта и под это дело мне клонировали его. Но когда я захожу то получаю ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Команда в CMD ping возвращает пакеты без потерь. В самом клонированном сервере ничего не менял. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело. Сервер Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)